# Vue auto restart when use fs.writeFile inside socket.io

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io

everytime client upload image use emit:

```
var image= {
   imageData: {base64:dataurl},
}
socket.emit("Toserver", image)
```

Vue always restart when npm run dev. On server:

```
socket.on('Toserver',function(data)
{
    fs.writeFile(__dirname+"/images/"+imageName, getBase64Image(msg.imageData.base64), 'base64', function(err) {
    if (err !== null)
    {
       // 
    } else {
       console.log("Upload image ok");
    }
  });
})
```

So It make speed of upload too slow even can not upload and display image on client side. Everyone who know this bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally. Reason is folder " images/ " . This folder inside static foder of Vue, so that why everytime I upload image, change happen and Vue auto disconnect and reconnect again. It take me from 8am to 3:23am no sleep to solve it, hope this can help another.